# Getting 'Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction'

Tags: python, mysql, locking, deadlock

I have multiprocessed application, and each thread executes the following python code:

```
while True:
    db_cursor.execute("SET autocommit=0;")
    db_cursor.execute("LOCK TABLES prqueue WRITE;")
    db_cursor.execute("SELECT MAX(id) FROM prqueue;")

    for record in db_cursor.fetchall():
        if record[0]:
            db_cursor.execute("DELETE FROM prqueue WHERE id='%s';" % record[0]);
            #db_connector.commit()
            db_cursor.execute("COMMIT;")
            db_cursor.execute("UNLOCK TABLES;")

            # some work that takes time

        else:
            db_cursor.execute("COMMIT;")
            db_cursor.execute("UNLOCK TABLES;")
```

Sometimes my processes die with OperationalError exception: `'Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction'`.

And the most strange thing here is that processes die on different lines. For example, error messages from 3 of them:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 114, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/crawler/Worker.py", line 122, in do_crawling
    db_cursor.execute("COMMIT;")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 174, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorclass, errorvalue
OperationalError: (1213, 'Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 114, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/crawler/Worker.py", line 122, in do_crawling
    db_cursor.execute("COMMIT;")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 174, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorclass, errorvalue
OperationalError: (1213, 'Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 114, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/crawler/Worker.py", line 109, in do_crawling
    db_cursor.execute("SELECT MAX(id) FROM prqueue;")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 174, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorclass, errorvalue
OperationalError: (1213, 'Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction')
```

Am I doing something wrong in this code? Completely exhausted with all these deadlocks.

Thank you.

Comment: Which line raises this error? Could you show us the whole traceback?

Comment: I'm afraid there is something wrong with your multiprocessing code, probably when they are dealing with critical region data. Can you post your multiprocessing part so that I can see why deadlock happened.